# WordPress as a backend only. How to output database content on public side without WordPress?

Tags: php, front-end

I'm a bit of a PHP MySQL newb but i feel i need to bypass WordPress for the frontend of a site i'm building (it is mainly just RSS and JSON feeds). I was wondering if there are any tutorials or advice I should follow on this or just cut straight to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to include `wp-load.php` at the beginning of your script/page like this :

```
require_once("/path/to/wordpress/wp-load.php");
```

You then have access to any WP functions. To manipulate the DB directly, have a look at [`wpdb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).

Comment: Great thanks. Does it still produce the same server load to call wp-load.php as it does call a normal WP page? I'm guessing both this methods would cause more load then just writing straight PHP and MySQL to talk to the database.

Comment: Yes it would cause more server load (though how significant I don't know), if you want to dump WP completely, then you can just talk to the DB directly with default PHP functions. Here's the [database description](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) for WP.

Comment: A much better approach would be to setup a RESTful API interface in Wordpress to serve the data to the app the builds the frontend. Then you can get the data and objects loaded correctly, every time, and still use it as a backend. DON'T EVER load the Wordpress files into your front-end app/site.

Answer (score 2):

You can even include `wp-load.php` without having it load the theme related files and functions to reduce the load.

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require_once('path/to/wordpress/wp-load.php')
```